# Changins Address URL All Afer "domain.com/" Without Reloading Page

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, pushstate

### My Multi-Level Menu Snippet

- Dashboard *- domain.com/Dashboard*
- Account

  - Dashboard *- domain.com/**Account/Dashboard***
  - Messages *- domain.com/**Account/Messages***
- Workstation

  - Dashboard *- domain.com/**Workstation/Dashboard***
  - Tasks *- domain.com/**Workstation/Tasks***

---

### My PushState

I've got a fully working `PushState` variable which will create the parts seen in bold above of how I would like the URL to show.

```
PushState = $(e.target).parentsUntil(".Menu").filter("li").children("a").map(function() {
                return $(this).find('span.Title').text().trim().replace(/&/g,"and").replace(/\s+/g, '-').replace(/Master-Dashboard/g,"Dashboard");
            }).get().reverse().join("/");

window.history.pushState(null, null, PushState);
```

---

### Problems I'm Having

On page load, upon clicking on `Account > Dashboard`, it does change the URL in the address bar to `domain.com/Account/Dashboard`, however upon then clicking on `Workstation > Dashboard`, the URL in the address bar changes to `domain.com/Account/Work-Station/Dashboard` and back again returns `domain.com/Account/Work-Station/Account/Dashboard`

---

### Questions

Without reloading the page and allowing the bask/forward feature, how can I change everything after the `domain.com/` instead of adding to up to the last `/` as it is currently doing.

Comment: You can try `replaceState()`

Comment: @Novice `replaceState()` has the same outcome as `pushState()` I'm afraid!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
history.pushState({}, "","/"+ PushState); 
// passes an empty state, an empty string, and a full URL with the leading slash
```

You need the slash to get rid of the previous path.